# HTTPoison to make a post request with Authorization in header.

Tags: header, elixir, httpoison

I am trying to make a http post request with `HTTPoison`.

I want to pass json data with header, which contains `"Authorization": Bearer #{token}`.

In order to achieve that, I have tried,

```
headers = [{"Authorization": "Bearer #{token}"}, {"Content-Type", "application/json"}] 
body = 
 %{
  id: id,
  name: name,
  ...      
 }
HTTPoison.post(url, body, headers)
```

But it triggers a syntax error that `syntax error before: "Authorization"`. And I have been searching for right syntax for headers but still no luck..

What is correct syntax for `headers` ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You have a `:` instead of `,` after `"Authorization"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe, the correct syntax should be as follows:

```
headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer #{token}", "Content-Type": "application/json"]
```

or, if you prefer the "tuple" way of defining keyword, this would be the equivalent:

```
headers = [{:"Authorization", "Bearer token"}, {:"Content-Type", "application/json"}]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: If you're using tuples, do this: [
      {"Content-Type", "application/json"},
      {"Accept", "application/json"},
      {"Authorization", "Bearer #{token}"}
    ]